# Remove space and replace with _ in phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Basically I want to take a row in a table which has entries 'example entry' and turn them into 'example_entry'. There are thousands of entries so I don't want to do it manually, obviously. How would I do this?

Comment: ah much appreciated, worked a treat!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE your_table
SET your_field = REPLACE(your_field, ' ', '_')
```

Comment: @stivlo: it happened to me so many times, it's normal here :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following query:

```
UPDATE table SET field = REPLACE(field, ' ', '_');
```