# SQL Replace spaces with underscore

Tags: mysql, replace

I am trying to run an SQL Query to replace the spaces in my filenames with an underscore:

```
UPDATE oc_product_image set image=replace(image,' ', '_');
```

I found this sql query here: [Remove space and replace with _ in phpMyAdmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7685843/remove-space-and-replace-with-in-phpmyadmin)

I am running it in the SQL tab in phpMyAdmin

When I simulate it I get this error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' ''_') FROM oc_product_image WHERE' at line 1

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: WHat is the data type of image?

Comment: Your query looks fine.  However, your error message is not associated with this query.

Answer (score 0):

Underscore is a special character in SQL.  Try escaping it with a backslash and see if that helps.